# Xargs pass input to command that contains a pipe

Tags: pipe, xargs

As a vehicle to understand how to manipulate binding precedence with pipes, I'm trying to print the path of one file per directory - for every directory:

```
find $PWD -type d | xargs --delimiter "\n" -I% -n 1 (find % -maxdepth 1 | head -1)
```

I get `no matches found: (find % -maxdepth 1 | head -1)`. Without the brackets I would get `xargs: find: terminated by signal 13` so I'm pretty sure we need to somehow make the pipes right-associative.

How do I pass xargs input to a command that contains pipes? (please don't tell me to use `-exec`, I want to learn how to manipulate binding precedence for other problems).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you are with xargs:

```
find . -type d|xargs -I % sh -c 'find % -type f -maxdepth 1 | head -1'
```

But remember: internal loop is **much** faster!

```
time find $PWD -type d | while read dir;do find $dir -type f -maxdepth 1 | head -1;done >/dev/null                                                                                       
    0m09.62s real     0m01.67s user     0m02.36s system
time find . -type d|xargs -I % sh -c 'find % -type f -maxdepth 1 | head -1' >/dev/null                                                                                                   
    0m12.85s real     0m01.84s user     0m02.86s system
```

Comment: Interesting. Again though, I want to learn the proper way to manipulate pipe associativity (if that's even possible). I thought creating a subshell in curly braces would do the trick but apparently not.

Comment: You have no other solution with xargs. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/xargs-with-multiple-commands-as-argument

Comment: Oh, so that's why you don't like xargs. Or at least, that's why you're turning me into an xargs hater :) Anything that throws away the power of the shell is a flash-in-the pan solution.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like xargs

```
find $PWD -type d | while read dir;do find $dir -type f -maxdepth 1 | head -1;done
```

Comment: Good to know there is this as an alternative. Though I hate loops ;)

Comment: You will _love_ loops soon! ;->

Comment: Even if I'm a functional programming activist? When writing java code I try to avoid loops at all costs. But as long as loops do only one thing then it's acceptable, though verbose :(

Answer (score 0):

And this is the fastest solution with everything is internal:

```
time find . -type d | while read dir;do for file in "$dir"/*;do if [ -f "$file" ]; then realpath $file;break;fi;done;done >/dev/null
    0m00.21s real     0m00.08s user     0m00.10s system
```

Unbeatable speed in shell. (I said I don't like xargs)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but here's how you could use a subshell using bash -c

```
find $PWD -type d | xargs --delimiter "\n" -I% -n 1 bash -c 'find % -maxdepth 1 | head -1'
```

Let me explain : bash -c generates a subshell taking a string argument being in this case the find command. Being a subshell, you can use any command you like, as long as you keep in mind that the command is within a string and that the subshell may have a different environment than the parent shell.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without putting the command in quotes? Among the reasons I prefer not to, you can't sit such commands across multiple lines, or see proper syntax highlighting.